# Show that there is no binary (5,3,4)-Code

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

this is a question I have in coding theory.
for reference, (n,M,d)-Code is a code of length n, containing M codewords and minimum distance d.
I am really struggling to grasp concepts like this, can I get a hint on how to start with the question? I am using a very old book called "A first course in coding theory by Raymond Hill" would appreciate it if I could get a hint or even a resource book I could use to practice and understand more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're being asked to prove that there's no way to create $3$ binary words of length $5$ such that each pair differs in at least $4$ places.

Comment: The question really is at is, show that there is no binary code of (5,3,4).

Comment: @Jos Which means what I wrote in my first comment.

Comment: look at the related questions that come up on the sidebar. some answer this. you need to show the maximum number of codewords with minimum distance $d$ and length $n$ is at most $M-1$.

Comment: I really don't get this I apologize...